# Should I delete my old answer, or edit it to completely turn it around?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/19177/is-ticket-to-ride-asia-played-with-stations/) was recently brought back to my attention due to a vote on my answer showing up in the achievements drop-down menu. It made me question my original submission so I grabbed the rules and ended up writing a new answer.

My old answer had some upvotes. I could have edited the old answer, keeping the votes, but the new answer was the complete opposite of the old one so I felt it was not the right way to go about this.

My question would be, should I have edited the old answer, or did I do the right thing by making a new answer and deleting the old one?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is your call as to what you did with your answer.

Personally, I would try to avoid deleting answers as my higher priority, and so I think you should have felt comfortable editing your original answer to correct it.

If your old answer was better than your new, I am pretty sure that you would not have gone to the trouble of writing the new one.

If others disagreed with your new answer then they have an easy tool to take that up with you via their right to downvote.

Answer (score -6):

You made the right thing by making a new one. SE doesn't have an edit history system, and they don't want people to play around with edits too much. The best thing to do is making new answers.

Comment: Actually there is a Edit History like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/268808/revisions) and to my knowledge SE encourages editing so long as they are meaningful and don't deviant from the author's intent

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it. Anyway I guess from the fact that you can't edit for more than 5 minutes the same answer that they don't want people to edit too much.

Comment: to my understanding if the same person edits within a grace period of their previous edit (which i think is 5 minutes) the history merges the edits to one entry which means if someone posts a question/answer then edits right away it's not recorded....at least to the general user (do idea about the mods). alot of times when i post a question/answer within 5 minutes i pick up mistakes and fix them. any sort of block from editing might be due to new user restriction which i have been skipping due to association bonuses, or mod restrictions for bad behavior

Comment: That wasn't what I meant. I don't say that you can't "edit it after 5 minutes that you've posted it", what SE limitates you to do is keeping the "edit" box open for more than 5 minutes and then posting.

But maybe it's due to the fact that I'm a new user, I don't know for sure.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you understand the edit system very well.